# Hi, how can I use forEach() in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have some `collection`. I want to search with some condition and data with `aggregate` code. Then update result with forEach code in `pymongo`. Is it possible?
For example i write a code:

```
db.users.find({age: {$gt: 18}}).forEach( function(myDoc) {db.users.updateOne({_id: myDoc._id }, {$set: {type: "older"}} );
```

I want to write this is in pymongo.

Comment: please add some sample input and your expected output

Comment: db.users.find({age: {$gt: 18}}).forEach( function(myDoc) { db.users.updateOne({_id: myDoc._id }, {$set: {type: "older"}} );

Comment: Please don't add comments to clarify; code is unreadable in comments. [Edit] your question instead.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, if you want to set a field on all records matching a certain criteria, you can just use [`update_many()`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_many) without the need for a for loop.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']
db.users.update_many({'age': {'$gt': 18}}, {'$set': {'type': 'older'}})
```

Comment: No my friend, i want to use foreach in pymongo. My main goal is that to use mongodb forEach in python (pymongo)

Comment: @Kamal I don't see a `forEach` method for a `pymongo` [`cursor`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/cursor.html).  Would you provide a link to the method you want to use?